# What is the purpose of Owners in TargetProcess3?

Tags: targetprocess

A user story has an Owner and Assignments. Trying to figure out the best use of Owners, Assignments and Roles.

Answer (score 2):

When you create an entity, your user becomes listed as **Owner**. Any item can have only one owner at a time.

An owner can always edit and delete his items, even if his role doesn't have edit or delete permissions for this type of items. This allows every person to edit or delete items they created by mistake.

Not everybody can change owner for an item; there is a special role permission 'can change owner' in the roles settings. If you don't have such permission (even with Add/Edit/Delete permissions) you still won't be able to change the  ownership.

Each entity can have unlimited amount of people **assigned** to it. Usually you assign a person to an entity, if this person is going to work on it.

Any user can always change the state of the items he's assigned to, even if his role doesn't have edit permissions for this type of items. This allows every person to mark their share of work as completed.

**Role** indicates what kind of work this person will perform (development \ analysis \ testing \ etc.). A set of available roles can be customized as described at https://guide.targetprocess.com/settings/how-to-customize-assignments-area.html

Role also affect what you'll see in your ToDo list: https://guide.targetprocess.com/filters/filters-for-personal-todo-list.html